# Angular2 on BlueMix, unable to run npm install on public folder

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud

I have a build set up to run npm install, I run it from the public directory, but it never adds the files to a node_modules folder in the public folder.  Any ideas?

Comment: On Cloud Foundry it's generally easiest to build your Angular 2 app then use a static buildpack for deployment of the resulting HTML and JS. As a bonus this also uses negligible resource.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you can share some code to look at.

Here is one Angular2 example that deploys on Bluemix using the static buildpack:
https://github.com/l2fprod/bluemix-hello-angular2

And this other example, based on Angular 2 Universal starter deploys on Bluemix and runs `npm install` as part of the deployment when the app starts in Cloud Foundry:
https://github.com/l2fprod/universal-starter

Comment: I attempted the first one, but everything gives me an error trying to install locally.

Comment: 269038 verbose stack Error: The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
269040 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
269041 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
269042 error node v4.6.0
269043 error npm  v2.15.9
269044 error code EPEERINVALID
269045 error peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
269045 error peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plu

Comment: I am just trying to implement the quickstart, which worked locally.  and then augment it online using the online git and build tools.  I was able to create a build object in build and deploy that seemed to compile the package.json in public, but the files never make it to the build.